# necessary access permissions

Tags: macos, ssd, permission

I have just installed a ssd drive into my iMac mid 2010 formatted the drive and installed Maverick and migrated only my applications from the old system drive which is now in a dock station. all when well but I cant save an image from Photoshop or any onto the new drive, an image from the firefox....

message:
"Could not save as “Untitled-1.jpg” because the file is locked, you do not have necessary access permissions, or another program is using the file. Use the ‘Get Info’ command in the Finder to ensure the file is unlocked and you have permission to access the file. If the problem persists, save the document to a different file or duplicate it in the Finder"

Info on the new drive has sharing & permissions- System (R&W), Wheel (RO), Everyone (RO)

what do I need to do??

Comment: If the file is in use by another program it can not be moved, but it can be save in the current open window to a new file

Comment: Does the SSD drive contain a recovery partition? If so, boot into recovery and reset Permissions and ACLS for the account > http://pondini.org/OSX/Password.html

Answer (score 1):

**Reset Your Home Folder Permissions and ACLS:**

1) Boot into your Recovery Partition holding down *command + R* at the startup chime

2) Select *'Terminal'* from your Utilities Menu Bar

3) Type: **resetpassword**

4) From the window that appears, select your boot volume and the appropriate user account

5) Click the **Reset** Tab under **Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLS**

6) Close the pane and quit Utilities

7) Select your boot volume when presented with choose startup disk and reboot your machine

**Edit (Courtesy of @Buscar's Point):**

If you don't have a Recovery Partition present, you can perform the same reset while logged in using the **Terminal** Command below. Triple click the line, copy it, and paste it into your prompt. Supply your password when asked:

```
{ sudo chflags -R nouchg,nouappnd ~ $TMPDIR.. ; sudo chown -R $UID:staff ~ $_ ; sudo chmod -R u+rwX ~ $_ ; chmod -R -N ~ $_ ; } 2> /dev/null
```

Command credit goes to Linc Davis of Apple Support Communities.

Answer (score 0):

Before we do any serious repairs lets find out if it is a simple matter.

- R&W permission or File in use.

In Finder look for the icon that looks like a house.

That is your home folder.

Right click on it and Get info.

At the bottom look for "your name" permission and change them to R&W.

<sup>You will have to unlock it first using the small lock icon bottom left on that window.</sup>

Once you passed this simple step lets check the File it self for been locked for some reson.

Again right click on the file and Get Info, look if it has been locked.

- Finally if none has worked then lets do the major step of repairing your permissions and ACLS (as pointed out by @njboot) using the <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> during the system start up.

Possible problem with that is if you do not have the Recovery installed it wont work.

In that case get the program called [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/downloadonyx.php) from the web and use it.

Comment: OK when I do this it has: jasonhall (Me) R&W and staff RO and everyone RO which is different to the ssd info in sharing & Permissions

Comment: Wheel applies to the boot volume, and shouldn't appear under user account: User account should be: Me (RW)/Staff(R)/Everyone(R ). Boot volume should be: System (RW)/Wheel(R)/Everyone(R ).

Comment: So that is all good then.

Comment: the message is what I get when trying to save from photoshop a file I've created in photoshop (NEW file) but will not save to the drive.

Comment: Resetting permissions and ACLS from the recovery partition should be the first step taken.

Comment: Ok thats done and it has worked for copying and image from the other hhd, BUT still wont save an image from photoshop or firefox to the ssd OR the hhd drive as if the programes are not allowing it to happen...

Comment: Are you using copy/paste in Finder?

Comment: have created a new file in photoshop and wont to save it in the ssd, with firefox if I search for an image and right click save as in the ssd location it failed. Have just tryed saving to the documents folder in users and it does. just wont save it outside of that

Comment: In FF open preferences and check the Save to: Select the correct location. Do the same in Photoshop.

Comment: just wont save it outside of the home folder, only in the HOME (jasonhall) directory. when I change Save to in FF it has a pic of the drivethen /and nothing after that??

Comment: ok we finally narrowed it down to: The home folder is the current user folder that contains all that users sub-folders (documents, Photos, Videos ect). Where do you want to save it to?

Comment: well it seams that you cant save directly on the ssd drive you have to create a folder and then save into that. thanks Buscar for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome, if any of answer helped you check one off so we can close this Q&A otherwise it will keep pooping up as not completed.

Comment: @Jason You *can* save directly to a drive if the permissions/ACLs are set correctly — it's not just a canonical rule that the root of a disk can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear ACLs recursively on a folder/drive by running:

```
chmod -R -N /path/to/location
```